# Youtube player api, Player is not loading in Opera

Tags: youtube-api

I want to embed youtube player, and also have to use its events. It works fine on chrome and firefox, But player does not load in Opera. I want it to work in Opera. 
Seeking for your help.

Thanks in advance.

I use following code.

```
//Load player api asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '330',
            width: '450',
            videoId: 'VIDEO_ID'
            //                events: {
            //                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            //                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            //                }

        });        
    }
```

Comment: I had this issue today in IE, the player would load but would not respond. I tried running some vanilla example code and the JS file that http://www.youtube.com/player_api drags in is causing errors on the page. Tried checking the dev console?

Answer (score 3):

For me it works in Opera after placing code for loading YT api in $(document).ready() function.
It's sick but works. In normal browser works without this trick...